# Seen 400 Bad Request error while getting file from Azure Blob Storage even file exists

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have word and Pdf files stored on the blob and recently I got error 400 Bad Request error while getting the file from Azure Blob Storage for a couple of files. These files are uploaded by the .net application and only a couple of files has a problem.

This was resolved by downloading files from the store and uploading back without any changes.

I need to understand why this is happening. Can you please help here.

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: where are the files stored? in a blob storage account v2 or data lake gen2? and how do you download them, via code or UI?

Comment: It is stored on Blob Storage and for fix downloaded from the store directly and uploaded to the store.